# PHP Extension Class Clash

Tags: php

For a project I'm working on, I'm using some 3rd party PHP classes for accessing the Twitter API.

These classes define an `OAuthException` class. `OAuthException` is already defined in my local version of PHP (as part of an extension), but not defined on the production server I will deploy my code on.

What's the best way to avoid declaring the class multiple times, while still ensuring it's declared at least once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the class exists before declaring it again?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

Answer (score 1):

> OAuthException is already defined in my local version of PHP (as part of an extension)

Installing the extension on the production server ?